# Test a python function in Robot Framework

Tags: python-2.7, testcase, robotframework

I am a new user and I didn't find a solution for a doubt about the execution of my script, wrote in python, in Robot Framework.

The script works when I execute it on python compiler but when I execute the test case on Robot Framework, this error is showed:

```
===========================================================================
TestProvaPower
===========================================================================
TestPowerAngelo                                                    | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'power' found.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TestProvaPower                                                     | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
===========================================================================
Output:  c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\RIDEjtznzw.d\output.xml
```

I think that this error is shown because it is necessary to pass the arguments and parameters.

Please, how can I pass these values in Robot Framework?

The test suite is:

```
** Settings **
Library           ../../../../../Users/User/workspace/TestAngelo18.09/TestProva22.py

** Test Cases **
TestPowerAngelo
    power    base    exponent
    push    ${base}    ${exponent}
```

While my Python script is:

```
base = input("Insert base")
exponent =input("Insert exponent")

def power(base,exponent):
    result=base**exponent
    print "%d to the power of %d is %d" %(base,exponent,result)

power (base,exponent)
```

Comment: Could you add your TestProvaPower suite to the question? It looks like you didn't import your python module correctly.

Comment: you should remove everything except the function from the library. the first, second and last line are only called only when the library is imported.

Answer (score 3):

As part of your module definition, you are getting input from the user. When a module is being imported, you cannot use the standard input stream so an EOFError occurs. Below is a modified version of your library that is still testable via direct execution.

```
def power(base, exponent):
    result = base**exponent
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    base = input("Insert base")
    exponent = input("Insert exponent")
    result = power(base,exponent)
    print "%d to the power of %d is %d" %(base, exponent, result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using complex path in the Library import try setting python path with pybot e.g.

```
pybot --pythonpath /path/to/libs/where/py/file/is
```

And in the test suite file import it using just the name e.g. without the .py suffix.

```
Library    TestProva22
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I deleted the input for base and exponent variables because I use Robotframework.

Answer (score 1):

RF treats arguments as strings by default.  For literals, you can surround them with `${}` or variables use `Convert To Integer` first. Something like this should work:

```
${result} =  power   ${2}  ${4}
Should Be Equal As Integers  ${result}  16
```